# How to set Template Language to Django in Pycharm Mac Osx Community Edition 5?

Tags: python, django, macos, pycharm

I have tried following https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-template-languages.html.

But i don't find any Template Language node any where in pycharm5 edition. Please help if there is an alternative to have Syntax Highlighting for Django Project templates.

Comment: django support is limited on community edition. which version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Django template syntax highlighting support is only available in PyCharm Professional Edition.